# How do git servers scale?

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, load-balancing, horizontal-scaling

Popular version control servers (like github) are likely having an immense amount of traffic and need a scalable & durable data storage. I was wondering how is this implemented in the background.

I have few guesses/assumptions on how it works but I'm not sure if they are 100% accurate:

- Repositories are probably stored on disk instead of some database solution (because git server is already self sufficient AFAIK)
- A single host to serve the entire traffic is probably not enough, so some load balancing is needed
- Since multiple servers are needed, each having their own storage, there is no point in keeping all repositories in all servers. (So I would expect each repository to be mapped to a host)
- For reliability, probably servers are not running on single hosts but rather on a cluster of replicates that are actually synced (maybe using kubernetes etc) and these are probably backed up periodically along with database backups.
- There probably is a main load balancer application that redirects the request to appropriate cluster (so it knows which repository is mapped to which cluster)

One other possibility is just storing the entire `.git` in a database as blob and have a scalable stateless application fetch that `.git` for each request, do operations, store the result again and the send response however this is probably a really inefficient solution so I thought it is unlikely to be the underlying mechanism.

So my main questions are:

- Do assumptions above make sense / are they accurate?
- How would one implement a load balancer application that all git requests are directed to the appropriate cluster? (eg. would mapping repositories with cluster id&ips, storing this in a database, and putting up a nodejs application that redirects the incoming requests to matching cluster ip work?)
- How would one go about implementing a git server that scales in general if above is inaccurate? (in case there are any better approaches)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to rely on guesses.

For GitHub specifically, the [githubengineering blog](https://githubengineering.com/) details what they had to use in order to scale to their current usage level.

Beside upgrading Rails or removing JQuery, on the frontend side, they have:

- [GLB: GitHub’s open source load balancer](https://github.blog/2018-08-08-glb-director-open-source-load-balancer/): At GitHub, we serve tens of thousands of requests every second out of our network edge, operating on [GitHub’s metal cloud](http://githubengineering.com/githubs-metal-cloud/).
- [MySQL High Availability at GitHub](https://github.blog/2018-06-20-mysql-high-availability-at-github/): GitHub uses MySQL as its main datastore for all things non-git, and its availability is critical to GitHub’s operation.
- [Stretching Spokes](https://github.blog/2017-10-13-stretching-spokes/): GitHub’s Spokes system stores multiple distributed copies of Git repositories. This article discusses how we got Spokes replication to span widely separated datacenters.

Regarding Kubernetes:

- "[Kubernetes at GitHub](https://github.blog/2017-08-16-kubernetes-at-github/)" (2017)
- "[Debugging network stalls on Kubernetes](https://github.blog/2019-11-21-debugging-network-stalls-on-kubernetes/) " (2019)